# How to stack machine learning models in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, ensemble-learning, stacking

I am new to machine learning and R.

I know that there is an R package called [caretEnsemble](http://github.com/zachmayer/caretEnsemble), which could conveniently stack the models in R. However, this package looks has [some problems when deals with multi-classes classification tasks](http://github.com/zachmayer/caretEnsemble/issues/8).

Temporarily, I wrote some codes to try to stack the models manually and here is the example I worked on:

```
    library(caret)
    set.seed(123)
    library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)
    data(AlzheimerDisease)
    adData = data.frame(diagnosis, predictors)
    inTrain = createDataPartition(adData$diagnosis, p = 3 / 4)[[1]]
    training = adData[inTrain,]
    testing = adData[-inTrain,]

    set.seed(62433)
    modelFitRF <- train(diagnosis ~ ., data = training, method = "rf")
    modelFitGBM <- train(diagnosis ~ ., data = training, method = "gbm",verbose=F)
    modelFitLDA <- train(diagnosis ~ ., data = training, method = "lda")

    predRF <- predict(modelFitRF,newdata=testing)
    predGBM <- predict(modelFitGBM, newdata = testing)
    prefLDA <- predict(modelFitLDA, newdata = testing)

    confusionMatrix(predRF, testing$diagnosis)$overall[1]
    #Accuracy 
    #0.7682927 

    confusionMatrix(predGBM, testing$diagnosis)$overall[1]
    #Accuracy 
    #0.7926829 

    confusionMatrix(prefLDA, testing$diagnosis)$overall[1]
    #Accuracy 
    #0.7682927
```

Now I've got three models: `modelFitRF`, `modelFitGBM` and `modelFitLDA`, and three predicted vectors corresponding to such three models based on the `test set`.

Then I will create a data frame to contain these predicted vectors and the original dependent variable in the `test set`:

```
   predDF <- data.frame(predRF, predGBM, prefLDA, diagnosis = testing$diagnosis, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

And then, I just used such data frame as a new `train set` to create a stacked model:

```
   modelStack <- train(diagnosis ~ ., data = predDF, method = "rf")
   combPred <- predict(modelStack, predDF)
   confusionMatrix(combPred, testing$diagnosis)$overall[1] 
   #Accuracy 
   #0.804878
```

Considering that stacking models usually should improve the accuracy of the predictions, I'de like to believe this might be a right to stack the models. However, I also doubt that here I used the `predDF` which is created by the predictions from three models with the `test set`.

I am not sure **whether I should use the results from the `test set` and then apply them back to the `test set` to get final predictions**? 
(I am referring to this block below:)

```
   predDF <- data.frame(predRF, predGBM, prefLDA, diagnosis = testing$diagnosis, stringsAsFactors = F)
   modelStack <- train(diagnosis ~ ., data = predDF, method = "rf")
   combPred <- predict(modelStack, predDF)
   confusionMatrix(combPred, testing$diagnosis)$overall[1]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you're doing here is what I refer to as "Holdout Stacking" (sometimes also called Blending but that term is also used for regular Stacking), where you use a holdout set to generate the training data for the metalearning algorithm (i.e. `predDF`).  I use the term Holdout Stacking to differentiate from regular [Stacking (or "Super Learning")](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/stacked-ensembles.html#stacking-super-learning) where you generate cross-validated predicted values from the base learners to generate the training data for  the metalearner algorithm (in your case, a Random Forest) rather than a holdout set (your `testing` frame).

The problem here is not how you're doing the stacking, but how you're evaluating the results.  Once you've used the `testing` frame to generate the `predDF` frame, you have to throw that data away and not use it for model evaluation.  In your example, you are also using the `testing` frame to evaluate the performance of the base models and the ensemble learner.

To fix this, just partition off another chunk of your data.  You should have three datasets:  `training`, `validation` and `testing`.  Use the `validation` set to create `predDF` (also known as the "level one" dataset in stacking terminology).

```
# Generate level-one dataset for training the ensemble metalearner
predRF <- predict(modelFitRF, newdata = validation)
predGBM <- predict(modelFitGBM, newdata = validation)
prefLDA <- predict(modelFitLDA, newdata = validation)
predDF <- data.frame(predRF, predGBM, prefLDA, diagnosis = validation$diagnosis, stringsAsFactors = F)

# Train the ensemble
modelStack <- train(diagnosis ~ ., data = predDF, method = "rf")
```

Then evaluate your base learners and your ensemble on the `testing` set to get a better idea of how the ensemble compares to the individual learners.

```
# Generate predictions on the test set
testPredRF <- predict(modelFitRF, newdata = testing)
testPredGBM <- predict(modelFitGBM, newdata = testing)
testPredLDA <- predict(modelFitLDA, newdata = testing)

# Using the base learner test set predictions, 
# create the level-one dataset to feed to the ensemble
testPredLevelOne <- data.frame(testPredRF, testPredGBM, testPredLDA, diagnosis = testing$diagnosis, stringsAsFactors = F)
combPred <- predict(modelStack, testPredLevelOne)

# Evaluate ensemble test performance
confusionMatrix(combPred, testing$diagnosis)$overall[1]

# Evaluate base learner test performance 
confusionMatrix(testPredRF, testing$diagnosis)$overall[1]
confusionMatrix(testPredGBM, testing$diagnosis)$overall[1]
confusionMatrix(testPredLDA, testing$diagnosis)$overall[1]
```

Lastly, as a suggestion, I'd recommend trying a GLM for the metalearning algorithm because they seem to perform better than tree-based models in my experience, though that is not always the case.

If you're specifically looking for multiclass support in Stacking, it will be available [soon](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-3960?filter=19301) in the [h2o](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h2o/index.html) R package.  If you don't need multiclass, then you can check out either the [SuperLearner](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SuperLearner/index.html) or [h2o](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h2o/index.html) packages to do stacking more easily than writing it all out by hand.  See the [`SuperLearner()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/SuperLearner/versions/2.0-22/topics/SuperLearner) or the [`h2o.stackedEnsemble()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/h2o/versions/3.10.5.3/topics/h2o.stackedEnsemble) functions to do Stacking with one line of code.